# React Native - security issue sensitive information in memory dump

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, security, axios

I am facing some security issues on my React Native App, specifically for Android. I am using Fridump to run some penetration testings and see what is on memory.

https://frida.re/docs/android/

https://github.com/Nightbringer21/fridump

I noticed that in memory there is a lot of information regarding the HTTPS request that happens in my app. This includes the POST to the authentication endpoint where I use the credentials that the user entered on the login form.

The information found in the strings.txt file created by Fridum contains info like this:

```
network_XMLHttpRequest_https://my-api-.com/authenticate
`!;@p
https://my-api-.com/authenticate8`i
{"Password":"value","Username":"value"}
```

This is just an example but in the report there are many other places with network_XMLHttpRequest_https info.

Some other tools that I am using:

- Redux Toolkit
- Redux persist
- Axios for doing HTTP requests
- Sentry for logging

The result of the Fridum report is the same even if I do a logout in the app, which deletes and replaces all the previous screens and leaves only the login form screen.

However if I close the app and open it again, the sensitive data and https request info is not anymore in the memory report, the issue starts after the first login api request.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Does anybody know a tool to check all possible Network middleware that the app might be using?

What I have tried:

- Review my redux store and it looks like I am not storing the password in the store. I am just using as a payload in an action where I dispatch the middleware which uses Axios for doing the post request to the authentication endpoint.
- Disable Sentry since I noticed that it logs data related to HTTP requests
  we

I expect to find a way to delete this HTTP request information from the memory

Comment: I am not sure what you expect. It is common knowledge that if you chose a language with garbage collector then securely deleting data in memory can be challenging or even impossible. If yo don't want this you have to use a programming language where you can manually overwrite memory of variables.

Comment: @Robert Hi Robert, I'm having the same issue as the creator of this question and found your comment during my search for a way to prevent fridump from exposing sensitive data such as passwords.

Am I understanding correctly that it is impossible to hide passwords written in inputs or sent over Axios from Fridump, since the data is saved in the RAM of the device until the automatic garbage collector devices to delete it?

Comment: @Onyx Yes. You can only minimize the number of copies in RAM. But for doing so I recommend to use plain Java/Kotlin without another execution runtime like react-native. In Java you can store sensitive data in `char[]` and if you don't need it anymore overwrite the array content to delete the contained data. `String` instances can not be overwritten so avoid them where possible. And HTTP requests should be not prepared in memory (e.g. as String) but directly written to the HTTP output stream.